# Spring Boot + Angular Application

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I am trying to build a Spring Boot Application where Angular would serve as frontend and Spring-Boot would serve as backend. I want to make it `war` deployable.

I tried searching many links on the web, the understanding I have got so far is: Spring-Boot would run on 8080 port and angular would run on 4200. I am confused as to how it would work as a single unit so as to be able to run it as an independent Spring-Boot application and also as `war` deployable.

I have seen other approaches on the web, creating separate `war` files for Spring-Boot and Angular, creating separate projects then dumping the dist generated of angular into the spring boot project but my requirement is not getting fulfilled.

I want to build a single Spring-Boot project and in the `webapps` folder of this project, I maintain all the Angular code. Thus I want to connect both Spring-Boot and Angular and be able to run it as Spring-Boot application and as `war` deployable.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-angular

Comment: When you deploy the application, everything will run from the server URL & port, if applicable. You run the development server on a different port than the backend to keep from having to build, deploy and restart the backend to see your frontend changes.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin), it really can do the trick.

You may check out this [github repository](https://github.com/htshame/March-8-jokester-quest-app). It's a simple Spring-boot + Angular app, only the packaging is `jar` and frontend code is in the separate module, but the idea of what you need seems to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://github.com/chiralsoftware/maven-typescript-obfuscation) shows using Spring Boot with Grunt to compile TypeScript. It's not exactly the same as Angular but it shows how to use the Maven frontend plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this open source template. It is maven multi model repository. Go to repository and click use this template button.

[Template](https://github.com/chamikara1998/spring_angular_template)